# What happens in  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I looked at the Dispose() method in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction (using a decompiler):

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        SNIHandle target = (SNIHandle) null;
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
          target = SqlInternalConnection.GetBestEffortCleanupTarget(this._connection);
          if (!this.IsZombied)
          {
            if (!this.IsYukonPartialZombie)
              this._internalTransaction.Dispose();
          }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {
          this._connection.Abort((Exception) ex);
          throw;
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ex)
        {
          this._connection.Abort((Exception) ex);
          throw;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
          this._connection.Abort((Exception) ex);
          SqlInternalConnection.BestEffortCleanup(target);
          throw;
        }
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Why does everyone say in forums that it is Rolling back in the dispose? Where does it rollback?

Comment: I believe the internal `Transaction` rolls back in its own `Dispose` - i.e. in `this._internalTransaction.Dispose();`

Comment: You are aware that if you killed the process, the server rolls back on its own, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@BlorgBeard is correct by saying "I believe the internal Transaction rolls back in its own Dispose - i.e. in this._internalTransaction.Dispose();". Writing it as an answer for other people. (See last statement)

**Code for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Dispose()  -- SEE LAST LINE:**

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  Bid.PoolerTrace("<sc.SqlInteralTransaction.Dispose|RES|CPOOL> %d#, Disposing\n", this.ObjectID);
  if (!disposing || this._innerConnection == null)
    return;
  this._disposing = true;
  this.Rollback();
}
```